# ClassCastException for xml security (TransformC14NExclusive)

Tags: web-services, security, cxf, jboss5.x

I have implemented a web service with cxf for my application (jdk 1.6.24) and it runs on jboss 5.1.0 fine.
After some time the web service is not working as it throws the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.security.transforms.implementations.TransformC14NExclusive cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.security.transforms.TransformSpi
        at org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.getTransformSpi(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transforms.addTransform(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.addReferencesToSign(WSSecSignature.java:599)
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:774)
        at org.apache.ws.security.action.SignatureAction.execute(SignatureAction.java:65)
        at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:206)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor.access$200(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:257)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:134)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:265)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
        at $Proxy566.getEntityRepresentatives(Unknown Source)
        at mycodeClient()
        at mycodeMethodCall()
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor325.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1509825954.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1509825954.java)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1509825954.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1509825954.java)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
```

The workaround I have used is removing the tmp, data and work folder from jboss.
It works fine afterwards, until it throws this error again much later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely cause of the exception is that your get the same class loaded by multiple classloaders.

You have to review how you package your application.

JBoss has some CXF jars and they are visible by default to your application.
If you also package CXF jars with your application, then you must fully understand JBoss classloading rules and how to tweak them.